# Failed to upgrade JRE from 1.6 to 1.8 on macbook

Tags: java, macos, java-8, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my jre. I've downloaded jre-8u121-macosx-x64.dmg and installed it.
When I check my java version on system preference, it is correct, like this:
[image]

However, when I check my JRE version on my terminal, it still shows that the Java version is 1.6, like this:
[image]
So what should I do to upgrade my JRE correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must install the full JDK version of Java 8 - 'jdk-8u121-macosx-x64.dmg'.

On macOS the JRE only installs support in the browser.

Comment: It works! This problem have troubled me for quite a long time. Thank you!